# $SE(3)$ and its tangent bundle

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, lie-groups, euclidean-geometry

I am working with the Euclidean Group $SE(3)$ and a doubt came to my mind.

If we define a tangent bundle of $SE(3)$ is it this tangent bundle itself and Euclidean Space?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the question.

As a manifold, $SE(3) \cong SO(3) \times \Bbb R^3$. $SO(3) \cong \Bbb RP^3$, and  is parallelizable so $TSE(3) \cong SE(3)\times \Bbb R^6$. But there is no natural structure of Euclidian space on $SE(3)$ since there is non natural addition here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never seen the symbol $\mathbb{R}P^3$. I know what $SO(3)$ is

Comment: Ok, without reference to $\Bbb RP^3$ I just said that $TSO(3) \cong SO(3) \times \Bbb R^3$. But $SO(3)$ as a really nice description as a manifold, it is the space of all lines through the origin in $\Bbb R^4$. If you are interested, you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space

Comment: @minidiable : If I did answered your question, don't forget to activate the little green mark so the question is marked as answered.